# Isn't there essentially only one "kind" of polymorphism in C++?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, overloading

And that is: **function overloading**.

What I mean is that

`base_ptr->derived_class_method()`

is essentially

`derived_class_method(base* this_ptr)`

which is polymorphism via **function overloading**.

Exactly the same can be said of polymorphism via templates, including CRTP, etc.

So it seems like, taking into account the most widespread implementations, all the "various kinds" of polymorphism boil down to **function overloading**.

Or am I missing something?

Comment: What, would you say, are the kinds of polymorphism that a programming language can have? Is there some kind in particular that, you think, that doesn't exist in C++?

Comment: You're missing a few things. You could start with [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29). (Your example is very unclear, by the way. How is it overloading if the `this` parameter always has the same type? Are you confusing overloading with overriding?)

Comment: Conceptually, the question does have a point though.

Comment: You're either confusing overloading with overriding or you are denying the existence of one of them, and also of the Liskov Substuittion Principle.

Comment: This is question of terminology "can i call it all function overloading?" - in some point of view - yes. Does it mean anything practically? No.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Isn't there essentially only one “kind”

Depends on how you define "kind". [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29) divides polymorphism into 3 categories: Ad hoc, parametric and subtyping. All these kinds of polymorphism are present in C++.

> And that is: **function overloading**

In  the context of C++ language, the words [*function overloading*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) have a specific meaning. With that meaning, neither templates, nor virtual functions can be called *function overloading*.

However, abstractly speaking yes, all polymorphism (in C++ and perhaps in computer science in general) boils down to choosing one function implementation over another.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a few things, but mostly one key difference : overloading is compile-time while overriding (i.e. `virtual`) can be runtime. With overloading, you could do this :

```
void make_a_sound(Cat const& cat)
{
  std::cout << cat << ": meow" << std::endl;
}

void make_a_sound(Dog const& dog)
{
  std::cout << dog << ": wurf" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  Cat c;
  Dog d;
  make_a_sound(c);
  make_a_sound(d);
}
```

But you could not do this:

```
class Animal
{
  virtual void make_a_sound() = 0;
};

void make_a_sound(std::vector<Animal*> const& animals)
{
  for (Animal* a : animals)
    a->make_a_sound();
}
```

In the first example, the compiler will select the right function to call at *compile time*. You could name the two functions differently (i.e. `make_a_sound_cat` and `make_a_sound_dog`) it it would work the same, being able to reuse the same name is just a convenience.

In the second example however, the compiler generates code so that, at *runtime*, your program will find out the exact nature of each animal and invoke the right method.

Answer (score 2):

There are **basically** three types of **Polymorphism** :

**1. Ad hoc

 2. Parametric

 3. Subtyping**

---

### 1. Ad hoc :

Ad-hoc polymorphism allows functions with the same name act differently for each type. (This is what you gave as your example)

Example :

```
int add(int a, int b) {
 return a + b;
}

std::string add(const char *a, const char *b) {
 std::string result(a);
 result += b;
 return result;
}
```

### 2. Parametric :

Parametric polymorphism provides a means to execute the same code for any type. It is achieved by templates in C++. (So given the definition, you can say it is also kind of automatic function overloading )

### 3. Subtyping:

Subtyping is achieved by use of derived classes through base class pointers and references. So in practicality we use subclasses and virtual methods for Subtyping. (This is not **function overloading**)

```
class Mammal 
{
public:
    Mammal() {};
    virtual ~Mammal() {};

    virtual std::string SendLoudNoise()
    {
        std::string str("I am a generic mammal");
        return str;
    }
};
class Dog : public Mammal {
public:
    Dog() {};
    virtual ~Dog() {};

    std::string SendLoudNoise()
    {
        std::string str("Woof woof!");
        return str;
    }
};
class Cat : public Mammal {
public:
    Cat() {};
    virtual ~Cat() {};

    std::string SendLoudNoise()
    {
        std::string str("--- Twitch my tail ---");
        return str;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Mammal* pAnimal[2] = { new Dog, new Cat};

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << pAnimal[i]->SendLoudNoise() << std::endl;
        delete pAnimal[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

You can't achieve the subtyping with function overloading. As it is '**Runtime Polymorphism**'.

Answer (score 0):

There are three in C++.

The main difference is in how independent the "polymorphs" are.

- Overloading is ad-hoc polymorphism.

It is ad-hoc because you're only using the same name to denote several different functions, which don't need to be related in any way.

Examples:

```
int   foo(int);
void  foo(const std::string&, double);
```

- Function templates provide parametric polymorphism.

These depend only on the interfaces of its parameters ("interface" in a broad sense; not Java's sense).

Example:

```
template<typename T>
T id(T t)
{
    return t;
}
```

This defines one function for each `T`, if `T` is copy-constructible.

A valid question to ask is "isn't this a kind of automatic overloading?", to which the answer would be that the difference isn't that great in C++.
In other languages, `id` might literally be just one function, usable with any type.

- "Virtual functions" - overriding - is subtyping.

These are firmly tied to a specific type hierarchy.

You'll note that overloading requires the polymorphs to have different prototypes, while the other two require the prototypes to be the same.

Also, virtual functions are (normally) bound at runtime, while the other two are always bound at compile-time (in C++).

Answer (score 0):

Here a complete list of all possible polymorphism in C++:

1. ad hoc polymorphism

   - coercion polymorphism (implizit cast)
   - overloading polymorphism, which can be

     - function overloading
     - operator overloading
2. universal polymorphism

   - inclusion polymorphism (subtyping)
   - parametric or generic polymorphism